# MySQL - Perform JOIN from serialized array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, serialization, join

I am creating a simple cart script with PHP and MySQL, and I am having trouble figuring out the fastest and most efficient way to perform this query.

I have a table called `carts` and a table called `products`. The `carts` table has a column called `contents` which contains a serialized array of item numbers. These items numbers correspond with the `pid` column of `products`.

What I am looking to do is have a query to pull the array of data and match the contents of the array to their corresponding rows in `products` so I can echo out all of the matching data for that product.

```
CREATE TABLE `carts` (
    `cart_id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `session_id` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `contents` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `first_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `last_name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `address` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `city` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `state` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `postal` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `country` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`cart_id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `session_id` (`session_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=7;

CREATE TABLE `products` (
    `pid` INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `itemTitle` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `itemNumber` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    `itemDescription` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    `imgArray` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    `visibility` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    `availability` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    `itemPrice` DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
    `accentColor` VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`pid`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=143;
```

Sample serialized array: `a:6:{i:0;s:3:"115";i:2;s:2:"82";i:4;s:2:"79";i:5;s:2:"58";i:6;s:2:"38";i:7;s:2:"85";}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it may technically be possible, you should not try to `JOIN` on a serialized column.  The fastest way to do it would be by using a bridge table between the cart and products.  It shouldn't be difficult to modify your code to work off of rows in the bridge table instead of a single serialized field.

Comment: Do you have any information you can point me to about these? I have never heard of such a thing.

Comment: @DevinPitcher It's called a `many to many` relationship and they are pretty common so you'll want to know about them.  Here's a link to some information: http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/many-to-many.html

Comment: Oh, I see now. I suppose I have done this before. So essentially it would be a table where, for example, I could have two columns, one that has the ID of the cart, and the ID of the product I wish to link to it, and for each new product they add to the cart, it simply adds a new row. Does that sound about right?

Comment: Ah, yep. I have done this in the past on other applications. I wasn't sure how fast or efficient it is though. However, I didn't think to use it in this application. Looks like I'll be making the switch though.